# What approaches exist for personal configuration in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customization

Consider we have typical Rails project under Git repository. I want to do my personal tweaks for configuration or code base (e.g. to simplify debugging). I don't want to do any extra work when switching, merging or pulling git branches. I don't want to affect other developers either. What approaches do you use (or can suggest) for that?

My approach is following:

- create a file (let say `personal_initializer.rb`) in `config/intializers/` directory
- in ~/.gitconfig define

  [core]

  excludesfile = ~/.excludesfile
- in `~/.excludesfile` add `config/intializers/personal_initializer.rb`
- do all hacks and tweaks in personal_initializer

Comment: you could as well add it directly to the `.gitignore` file in your project

Comment: And what if you wish to add a gem for debugging? What's the point of such setup? If your ideas make work easier I think other people may wish to use it as well, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I would add development.rb file to .gitignore and create a development.example.rb

development.rb would contain all my personal configuration, and wont be pushed to other devs local sources

development.example.rb would contain default configuration, so when a new dev pull the sources he must copy development.example.rb to development.rb and tweak it as he wish

Comment: the problem is that I cannot do that. at least it's quite problematic to persuade large team to do that.

Comment: If you cannot organize your team then the problem is not technical :) good luck